# Is software packaging considered as a service duty?

Tags: software, open-science, service-activities

I create from scratch and/or maintain software packages on behalf of the Debian GNU/(Linux|kFreeBSD) distribution; Debian serving as base for other apt-distributions as Ubuntu. Most of `my' packages are clearly (and purposely) only of interest for researchers, mainly in applied and pure mathematics and related fields; I am a mathematical/theoretical physicist. I also try to address to a large audience by focussing on software that enhance and/or are dependency of large/huge suites.

In particular, by this way, I am trying to promote (Open-Source) Computer Algebra System (CAS) suites, that is to say, suites as GAP, Singular, Sage, etc. CAS are cruelly lacking in Debian, the main reason is that they involve a lot of software from very different origins that are written in various styles and languages. Bringing decent CAS in Open-Source distributions (as the ones based on Debian) represents a clear advantage for the academic world, the current alternative being to buy rather expensive commercial CAS whose part of the the code is hidden or to hire a dedicated installer. I guess that we can say that a CAS is for symbolic computation what TeX is for text composition.

Henceforth, I think that it is fair to say that the involved hacking work goes beyond the Debian community and that it can really have an impact inside the academic world. One can argue that it is a *community volunteering*, but reviewing, referring, preparing seminars and so forth are also volunteering works. Research depends more and more on open-source software and packaging is a long process which looks very similar to the reviewing process: it involves exchange with upstream maintainers, it corrects local code to share it with a global audience in a transparent way, it allows to install and employ software written by and for the academic community in a straightforward way as the publishing process allows a global community to read a Paper in a very pleasant fashion.

However in most of the adverts for academic staff positions which enumerate a long list of service duties ending with a etc, this hacking work is not present, hence my question.

Comment: Considered by who? Considered for what purpose?

Comment: Considered by University Administrations as service duty by academic staff (e.g., lecturer, assistant professor, ...).

Comment: Ask your department chair or similar.

Comment: I think that it is a _community volunteering_, rather than an _academic service duty_. Even though the software you maintain is focused on academia, this activity is IMHO _too narrow_ and _too detached_ from a _comprehensive / diverse_ academic service to be considered as such.

Comment: If you want to profit from all the effort you put in writing software, sell it.

Comment: @CapeCode First packaging is not writing; second if I wanted to sell to make profit for my own, I would not have engaged in an academic process. You answer sounds a bit OT.

Comment: It can, depending on its volume, count towards community contribution in your CV. More if you write a package, less if it's just packaging existing modules.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Which community contribution ? Each Debian contributor/Maintainer/Developer has her/his own [Debian Quality Assurance](https://qa.debian.org/) chart. But I guess that you meant the academic community, what is far harder to quantify.

Comment: All I am saying: assume that you are the packager/maintainer of a scientifically relevant software package, that is something that would make a (minor) plus tick in a CV. It's not going to tip the balance, but it may make a positive contribution to the overall picture if it fits. If this is your only software-relevant activity, it's probably irrelevant, but if there is a collection of software-relevant features in your CV, it might catch an extra eye as it indicates that you are community-oriented. Don't over interpret it.